# Update and delete not working with Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, persistence, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a class, Student and the generated Endpoint class for it. ListStudents and insertStudents methods work without any problems, but update and remove don't cause any change in the datastore. The methods don't throw any errors and the call returns, but no changes are made.
My endpoints code is mostly the code generated by google plugin for eclipse:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "removeStudent", path="remove_student")
public void removeStudent(@Named("email") String email) {
EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try {       
        Student student = getStudentByEmailName(email);         
        mgr.remove(student);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
}
```

Entitiy manager getter method:

```
private static EntityManager getEntityManager() {  
return EMF.get().createEntityManager();
}

@ApiMethod(name = "updateStudent")
public Student updateStudent(Student student) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try {
        if (!containsStudent(student)) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
        }
        mgr.persist(student);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return student;
}
```

And my EMF class:

```
public final class EMF {
private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

private EMF() {
}

public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
    return emfInstance;
}
```

}

The client that uses this endpoint is Android. I have only tried testing on my local server.
Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your student entities indexed by email?

This is a typical issue when you move to nosql and expect all queries to work without indexes.

Note that records inserted before defining index would not be in index.

Answer (score 0):

The datastore is eventually consistent and your code should work. What is the return value that you get in the Student object from your `updateStudent` method.

As much as I don't want to, after you do a `mgr.persist(...)` , add `mgr.flush()` and see if that makes a difference.